# Rewriting URL with .htaccess in folder

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a website in mydomain.com/website and I want to rewrite for example /website/viewpage.php?page_id=1 to /website/mypage-1.html

If my website would be in root directory it's simple, but how to make it in this way?

I've tried this way, but it only works with root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)\.html$ viewpage.php?page_id=$1 [L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep this code in `/website/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/

RewriteRule ^.+?-([0-9]+)\.html$ viewpage.php?page_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```